# Datagrid itemsource twoway databinding not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I try to build a wpf based application with datagrid and itemsource is bound to an object.

Xaml

```
   <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Folders, Mode=TwoWay}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Path" CanUserResize="False">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="260"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="30"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="30"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path}">
                                <TextBox.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                                <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Arrow"></Setter>
                                            </Trigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </TextBox.Style>
                            </TextBox>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

and the generated source code

```
   public partial class FolderControl : UserControl
    {
        public FolderViewModel FolderViewModel = new FolderViewModel("SourceFolders.xml");

        public FolderControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = FolderViewModel;
        }

        private TextBox GetTextBoxInstance(object obj)
        {
            var btn = (Button) obj;
            var parent = (Grid) btn.Parent;
            var text = (TextBox) parent.Children.Cast<UIElement>().Select(tb => tb).First();
            return text;
        }

        private void OpenFolder_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var text = GetTextBoxInstance(sender);
            Win32.FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new Win32.FolderBrowserDialog();
            Win32.DialogResult showDialog = fbd.ShowDialog();
            text.Text = fbd.SelectedPath;
        }

        private void OpenFile_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var text = GetTextBoxInstance(sender);
            Win32.OpenFileDialog ofd = new Win32.OpenFileDialog();
            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                // If find the same file on collection, show msg error
                if (FolderViewModel.Folders.Any(file => file.Path == ofd.FileName))
                {
                    MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show(EN.TEXT4, "Info", MessageBoxButton.OK); 
                }
                else
                {
                    text.Text = ofd.FileName;
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

and the viewModel(i not gonna show the whole code here, just what is necessary)

```
public class FolderViewModel : UploadViewModelBase
{
    public BindingList<Folder> Folders { get; set; }

    public FolderViewModel(string filename)
        : base(filename)
    {
    }
```

Here I use bindinglist generics type collection instead observecollection, for observe change on the collection.
And the last file, the model

```
public class Folder : ObservableObject
{
    private String _path;
    private OsType _os;
    private String _strOs;

    public String Path
    {
        get { return _path; }
        set { _path = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.Path); }
    }

    public OsType Os
    {
        get { return _os; }
        set { _os = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.Os); }
    }

    public String StrOs
    {
        get { return _strOs; }
        set { _strOs = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.StrOs); }
    }
}
```

the whole problem is here, when I change the content from a row, it does not change on the collection object. What i do wrong?

Comment: Your *Datagrid itemsource twoway databinding not working* title is totally invalid and does *not* describe your problem. What do you think that a `Two-Way Binding` on an `ItemsSource` property would even do??

Comment: Have you tried putting an UpodateSourceTrigger in the binding, like so, "{Binding Folders, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"

Comment: @Bearcat9425, if you don't know the answer, don't make suggestions... you're just showing your lack of knowledge on data binding. What do *you* think that a Two-Way Binding on an ItemsSource property would even do?? Or an `UpdateSourceTrigger`???

Comment: @Sheridan the twoway databinding should change on both side, in my example on grid and collection, i guess

Comment: Your totally missing my point. The `ItemsSource` property only supports `OneWay Binding`s, so setting `Mode=TwoWay` on it is pointless.

Comment: ok, how do you know that? Where can i find this information

Comment: Where do you think? On the [`ItemsControl.ItemsSource` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN... always MSDN.

Comment: And how I can do it in two databinding?

Comment: `Two-Way Binding`s are used on the controls that display *and can edit* data bound values, not the container control's properties... but not `TextBox`es, because they have `Mode=TwoWay` set as default (again... from MSDN, `TextBox` page)... always MSDN.

Comment: @Sheridan you are the master of wpf. I solve the problem `<TextBox Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">`

Comment: @zero_coding, I'll add this useful information into an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have had some confusion with data binding. Here are some tips:

`Two-Way Binding`s are used on the controls that display *and can edit* data bound values, not the container control's properties... this means that there is no point on setting `Mode="Two-Way"` on an `ItemsSource` property, because if you look at the [`ItemsControl.ItemsSource` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN, you'll see that it only supports `One-Way Binding`s.

As mentioned, setting `Mode="Two-Way"` should only be used on controls that can display *and can edit* the data bound values. However if you look on the [`TextBox.Text` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.text%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN, you should see a section named *Dependency Property Information*. In this section, you can see that the `Textbox.Text` property binds `Two-Way` by default, so you never have to apply that setting to it.

So, while you say that your solution was to use the following:

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ... />
```

I'm fairly sure that it was just the `UpdateSourceTrigger` property that you needed to set, because as we all know now, setting `Mode=TwoWay` on the `Textbox.Text` property does nothing:

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ... />
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see at least the following two problems in your code:

1. The `DataGrid` never modifies the `ItemsSource` reference itself (only its "contents"), therefore you should not set `Mode=TwoWay`.
2. Most of WPF is designed to work with collection data types that implement [INotifyCollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx). `BindingList<T>` does not implement this interface. Therefore, you better use `ObservableCollection<T>`, which implements this interface.

Furthermore,

```
public BindingList Folders { get; set; }
```

seems to be incorrect, if your `BindingList` is this one: [MSDN documentation for BindingList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It probably should be

```
public BindingList<Folder> Folders { get; set; }
```

But maybe it is just a typo in your question.